# Double declaration of same structure in DelegateBase.h?

Tags: unreal-engine4

What is the purpose of this?

I put an image because the code gives me formatting problems. Sorry people.
[image]

Comment: It's a forward declaration

Comment: Looks like an oversight.

Comment: First forward declaration is not enough?